# How to write gzcon output to a variable in R?

Tags: r

The documentation for [gzcon](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/gzcon.html) states:

> Use a writable [rawConnection](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rawConnection.html) to compress data into a variable.

Here's my code:

```
output <- raw(0)
z <- rawConnection(output, "wb")
zz <- gzcon(z, text = TRUE)
writeLines("TEST", zz)
close(zz)
```

So at this point, I'm not sure how I can retrieve the compressed data.

I would like to retrieve the value using `rawConnectionValue` but `gzcon` has messed up z.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Were you ever able to find an answer? I have the exact same question.

Comment: No, we didn't. We ended up using using the `memCompress` function instead.